# As a dependent of a G4 visa holder, can I work in the USA past the age of 23?

Tags: employment, immigration, visa

My mother works on an international organization and holds a G4 visa. I, as her son/dependent, received a G4 visa as well. Currently I have an Employment Authorization Card (EAC) which allows me to have a job in the USA. The EAC is given to me as long as I am a full time student. However, I read that the EAC can only be renewed until the age of 23. Currently I am 22 years old and will be 23 in 6 months. Since I am a full time student I need the EAC in order to have a job and pay for my BS. So far I have completed 2 years of college at a community college and I have transferred to a university where I plan to get a BS degree in computer programming for simulations/games in the next 2 years.

About a year ago, when I was renewing my EAC, a lady who works at the international organization where my mother is employed told me that the EAC renewal limit had just changed and now it could be renewed until either age 24 or 25 (I can't remember which). Recently however, another lady who works at the international organization told my mother that it can only be renewed until age 23. Which is true? If it's the latter, is there any way I could work past age 23 so I can finish my education?

Comment: Before wondering about your employment authorization, you should worry about your G-4 status, and that indeed may be the problem when you turn 23 (see https://www.imf.org/external/np/adm/rec/policy/oth/g4.htm, for example).  If you become ineligible for G-4 status, you may have to get a student visa to remain in the US, and your eligibility for employment will of course at that point be governed by your new immigration status.  If you've lived in the US for long enough, you may qualify for a green card as a special immigrant.

Comment: You might get a better reception on [Expatriates.SE], where this sort of question is more topical.